# Interpretar respuesta de http en Android

Tags: android, http, socket

¿Cuál es la mejor tecnología para establecer una conexión entre una aplicación android y un servidor (en mi caso PHP, pero esto es secundario), REST, Socket, WebSocket, SOAP,...? (Simplemente mencionar la mas utilizada o mejor, no necesito explicaciones).

Actualmente estoy comenzando a utilizar `HttpUrlConnection()`. Envío desde mi aplicación android, mediante el método POST, un formulario a un archivo PHP en el servidor, para que guarde ciertos datos en una base de datos.

No sé como puedo hacer para, en la aplicación android, obtener la respuesta de la página web, es decir, si ha habido algún problema en la inserción de los datos (registros duplicados, algún formato erróneo,...).

Adjunto el código (funciona) de la conexión para la inserción de los datos:

```
private void enviarDatos() throws IOException {
    //Lo siguiente solo es temporal, para que me deje hacer pruebas en el hilo principal
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)     
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();   
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {   

        URL url = new URL("http://"+miip+":8080/insert.php");  
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);    
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

        String data = "nombre="+nombre.getText().toString()+"&"+"apellidos="+apellidos.getText().toString()+"&"+"pass="+pass.getText().toString()+"&"+"email="+email.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);       
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length); 

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(data.getBytes());   
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No existe conexión",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Mostrar errores
    }
}
```

Es para un registro de usuarios. 
¿Es posible obtener respuesta al envío del formulario de esta forma?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*Cuál es la mejor* tecnología depende para cada tipo de proyecto y sus requisitos, no hay una tecnología mejor que otra, sino que algunas se ajustan mejor al proyecto que otras, así que sin conocer el proyecto poco puedo decirte.

Si no me equivoco la más utilizada suele ser REST que ni siquiera es una tecnología sino una definición de un principio de arquitectura.

Respecto a lo de recibir respuesta del servidor sí, puedes. Depende como lo tengas en el servidor devolverás los datos de una forma u otra.

Para recibir la respuesta en el cliente simplemente añade lo siguiente dentro del if de conexión "correcta":

```
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String linea;
StringBuffer respuesta = new StringBuffer();
while((linea = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    respuesta.append(line);
    respuesta.append('\r');
}
rd.close();
System.out.println("Respuesta del servidor:" + respuesta.toString());
```

Te mostrará lo que has recibido del servidor, ahora sólo te queda tratar los datos según necesites.

Comment: Si alguien pudiera explicar el porqué de los votos negativos se agradecería.

Comment: Opino lo mismo, tu respuesta si fue efectiva. Creo que puede ser por la pregunta de cual es mejor tecnología, pero sinceramente no lo entiendo, aquí se debería de ayudar, y en caso de que se haya conseguido esa ayuda, que pueda servir a los demás. Por lo que veo aquí, hay demasiado abuso de autoridad, aunque sea contraproducente para los todos. Esperaba otra cosa de SOes.

Comment: Es raro, normalmente cuando uno vota negativo deja un comentario, ya que como tú bien dices estamos para aprender y tanto de lo bueno como de lo malo se aprende. Tanto los que preguntamos como los que respondemos, comentamos o simplemente consultamos, pero bueno, habrá que entre todos ayudar a mejorar la comunidad. Saludos